# Activating reveal.js in WordPress 4.2.2

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, reveal.js, fieldmanager

I want to use [`reveal.js`](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/) in the [WordPress theme](http://themeforest.net/item/faculty-responsive-academic-wordpress-theme/6817161) of my website, which uses WordPress 4.2.2. I followed the instructions by alleyinteractive [here](https://github.com/alleyinteractive/revealjs-wp-theme).

1. I downloaded [reveal.js for WordPress](https://github.com/alleyinteractive/revealjs-wp-theme).
2. I extracted it into `public_html/wp-content/themes/revealjs-wp-theme-master`.
3. I downloaded [`Fieldmanager`](https://github.com/alleyinteractive/wordpress-fieldmanager) plugin and extracted the zip file into `public_html/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-fieldmanager-1.0.0-beta.2`.
4. I can see the theme in `wp-admin` as shown below:

[image]

However, I am afraid to activate the theme as I may lose the content of my website. Could someone tell me how I can create `reveal.js` presentation along with my current [WordPress theme](http://themeforest.net/item/faculty-responsive-academic-wordpress-theme/6817161)? What happens if I activate `reveal.js` theme? I learned how to make a presentation by `reveal.js` on my local computer but I don't know how I can have it on my website.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in [here](http://wptavern.com/create-a-website-for-your-presentation-slides-with-the-reveal-js-theme-for-wordpress):

WordPress users who want to create and host their own slides now have the option to use the Reveal.js theme for WordPress. It installs just like any other theme and requires the addition of the Fieldmanager plugin. **The theme takes over the entire website so it should only be used on a site dedicated to displaying presentation slides.**